# For loop runs again after condition is met

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on crating a function that adds data from numerous sheets in a Google Sheets document. The function creates production sheets that has a name and data slot as well as column titles for data that the function will paste into the sheet "Print". I am having an issue where a for loop seems to run an additional time even though the conditions are met as far as I can tell. Here is the code I have so far, its ugly but I'm just building this for myself.

```
function pasteToPrint(){

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var sheetName;

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  var lastCol;

  var lastRow;

  var a;

  var x;

  var y;

  var z;

  var array1 = [];

  var array2 = [];

  function getNextPage(){ // spreads subsequent data set to page break for printing 
    x = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getLastRow();
    y = x/32;
    y = Math.ceil(y);
    z = 32*y;
    return z;
  }

  for(var i = sheets.length-1; i > 4; i--){ // loops through the appropriate sheets and pushes to array1
    lastCol = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheets[i].getName()).getLastColumn()+1;
    lastRow = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheets[i].getName()).getLastRow()+1;
    array1.push(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheets[i].getName()).getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastCol).getValues());
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){ 
    for(var j = 0; j < array1[i].length; j++){
      // Looking for data that has a value grater than 0 at .slice(2,3)
      if(array1[i][j].slice(2,3) > 0){ // Ref1
        for(var k = 0; k < array1[i].length; k++){ // here I push that data to array2
          if(array1[i][k].slice(2,3) > 0){ // ref 2
            array2.push(array1[i][k]);
          }
        }
        ui.alert(array2+" test 1"); // lets me know the content of array2
        ui.alert(array2.length); // tells me the length just to be sure
        for(var l = 0; l < array2.length; l++){ // decides where to paste the next data set
          if(spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getLastRow()>1){ // ref 3
            a = getNextPage(); // returns the next 32nd line
          }
          else {
            a = 1; // starts at row 1
          } 
          // this next section is column formatting for the beginning of the production sheet
          // ref 4
          spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getRange(a,1).setValue("Name:");    
          spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getRange(a,3).setValue("Date:");
          a++; // moves to the next row
          spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getRange(a,1).setValue("Product");
          spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getRange(a,2).setValue("Work Order");
          spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getRange(a,3).setValue("Planned Production");
          spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getRange(a,4).setValue("Product Produced");
          spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getRange(a,5).setValue("Steel Shortage");
          spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getRange(a,6).setValue("Notes");
          a++ // moves to the next row
          // ref 5
          for(var m = 0; m < array2[l].length-1; m++){ // HERE IS THE PROBLEM LOOP
            ui.alert(array2[m]+" test 2"); // I see this run an additional time after m = length
            spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getRange(a,1).setValue(array2[m][0]);
            spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getRange(a,2).setValue(array2[m][4]);
            spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Print").getRange(a,3).setValue(array2[m][2]);
            a++; 
          }
        }
        array2 = []; // array2 is emptied 
        break; // First if statement checking .slice(2,3) now has the function go to the next sheet
      }
    }
  }

  ui.alert("Function ended"); // just letting me know

};
```

imagine that there are numerous sheets in this document with data like the following except that there might be hundreds of rows after the column titles with different part numbers and so on

```
Material  Req Planned Quantity MTs Planned Order
AI UPC300 1   1                86  12744851
```

The Plan Quantity column is what the .slice(2,3) is looking for. By default when I paste the original data into the sheets from my inventory system the value of Planned Quantity will be 0. After I have gone through the document and planed production, this means I have assigned a value to planned quantity greater than 0, I will run the function to paste the data to the print sheet. There could be hundred of items but I will only plan a portion of them, that's why this is handy. I can't share the full document I'm working with because it has sensitive data in it. If you create a google sheet with one sheet named print and a second sheet named whatever you want you can then paste the example data on rows 1 and 2 of the second sheet and you will see the error I get which is

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 138, file "arrayTest")

You must also change `for(var i = sheets.length-1; i > 4; i--)` to `for(var i = sheets.length-1; i > 1; i--)`, change the 4 to a 1. I have more code in my document but it is comprised of separate functions from this function.

I have added an image below that showcases how this would look before I utilize the function as well as how the Print sheet would look after the function has run. I had to screenshot this unfortunately so the data is condensed. Imagine that each section of data you see, green, blue, and white, are on their own sheets. For clarity the data in green would be contained in TestSheet1, the data in blue in TestSheet2, and the Print sheet would be totally blank before this function runs. Once I have entered my planned quantities in the Planned Quantity columns of TestSheet 1 and 2 I would then run the function. This would result in the data being pasted to the print page. I have added "ref" comments to the code to show where each step of the following explanation occurs. The function runs in this order: 1) The function will determine if a sheet has any values greater than zero in the Planned Quantity column, "ref 1". 2) The function would them loop through the sheet and push any row that met this criteria to array2, "ref 2". 3) The function will determine where to paste the data into the Print sheet based on data that may already by pated to the sheet, row 1, row 32, row 64, and so on, "ref 3". 4) the function will paste a header above the soon to be pasted data. This header include name, date, and column titles. 5) Once the header is placed the function will loop through array2 and paste is contents to the Print sheet, "ref 5". 6) the function will set array2 so that `array2 = []` and will then repeat the process for the next sheet until all the sheets have been gone over and there is no more data to paste into Print, "ref 6".

[image: Image of spreadsheets: "Print" only image of tab, "TestSheet1" cells in green, "TestSheet2" cells in blue, an example of the Print sheet after the function correctly runs]

Comment: @Cooper obviously it would be cool to have all of this in less lines but I'm more interested in it just working as my primary goal is to do my job faster. Like I mentioned in my question you can make a new Google sheet document and paste in the data to see the error I'm getting. If you add a 3rd page and past the data in again you will see how my idea for pasting data from a separate page is supposed to be spaced out for printing although the function does not work because the loop runs an additional time.

Comment: provide [mcve] in the future

Answer (score 1):

The `m` loop is unnecessary. It's looping over current row(`l`s) columns. A [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) looks like this:

```js
const array2d = [1, 2, 3].map(num => new Array(6).fill(num));//boilerplate to simulate array2
console.log({array2d});
for (var l = 0; l < array2d.length; l++) {
  for (var m = 0; m < array2d[l].length - 1; m++) {
    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM LOOP
    // alert(array2d[m] + ' test 2'); // I see this run an additional time after m = length
    console.log(array2d[m][0], array2d[m][2], array2d[m][4]);
  }
}
```

#### Solution:

Remove the loop entirely.

```
a++; // moves to the next row
//          for(var m = 0; m < array2[l].length-1; m++){ // HERE IS THE PROBLEM LOOP
//           ui.alert(array2[m]+" test 2"); // I see this run an additional time after m = length
spreadsheet
  .getSheetByName('Print')
  .getRange(a, 1)
  .setValue(array2[l][0]);
spreadsheet
  .getSheetByName('Print')
  .getRange(a, 2)
  .setValue(array2[l][4]);
spreadsheet
  .getSheetByName('Print')
  .getRange(a, 3)
  .setValue(array2[l][2]);
a++;
//          }

    }
```

#### Best practices:

- [Essential optimization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_common_tasks#OptimizeScripts)

Comment: I have not had a chance to edit the code yet but the point of looping after the header text is pasted to the Print sheet is so that there will be one header per section of data. I have also added an image of how things would look as well as a detailed explanation of the step by step process.

Comment: @Darth `array2` contains rows. There is no point in adding headers for each `l`. Move the add headers part out of the `l` loop.

Comment: I don't think I explained this part well enough. In my actual work environment I will have this function looping through an average of 17 sheets. In total I could have somewhere in the neighborhood of 200 to 300 entries being pasted to the Print page. Each page will have their planned production quantities pasted to the print page at the same time, as in all the data will be pasted to one Print page. Therefore each sheets section of posted data will need to have a header above it. So when I run the loop I need to have a header, I need to loop through the data and paste, page break, and repeat.

Comment: @Darth I don't think you understand what I'm saying. Tell you what, Provide a sample `array2` logged with 1 new spreadsheet containing 2 new sheets with 5rows in each sheet with screenshots  in your question.(eg: array2=[[xyz,10,0,...],[abc,15,0...],.....])